# ¿Por qué me da este error: expected primary-expression before

Tags: c++

Deseo resolver una ecuación compleja por el método de Newton y que converja cuando se haya alcanzado una de las dos condiciones, una vez que el usuario introduzca el número complejo y el número de iteraciones:

este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
#include <complex>
float epsilon;
int N;
double r;
double im;
float Ecuacion(float zi) {
  // Con la ecuación: z^3 - 1
  return pow(zi, 3) - 1;
}

float Derivada(float zi) {
  // Con la ecuación: 3z^2 
  return pow((3 * zi), 2);
}

int main() {
std:: complex<double> zi(r,im);
std:: cout << "Introduzca el orden de iteraciones" << std:: endl;
std:: cin >> N;
std:: cout << "Introduzca la precisión en formato científico" << std:: endl;
std:: cin >> epsilon;
std:: cout << "Introduzca el número complejo a resolver" << std:: endl;
std:: cout << "Parte real" << std:: endl;
std:: cin >> r;
std:: cout << "Parte imaginaria" << std:: endl;
std:: cin >> im;

// Método de Newton


double fzi = Ecuacion(std:: complex<double> zi);
double f_zi = Derivada(std:: complex<double> zi);
double zi_1 = std:: complex<double> zi - std:: complex<double>(fzi / f_zi);

do {
    for (int i = 0; i <= N ; i++){
       std:: cout << zi_1 << abs(fzi) << std:: endl;
    }
}

while (zi_1 <= N || abs(fzi) < epsilon );{

}
  return 0;
}
```

¿Están mal definidas las variables donde están van a ir los números que se introduzcan?

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Están mal definidas las variables donde están van a ir los números que se introduzcan?

Lo que está mal en ese caso es el uso y abuso de las variables globales. No hay ninguna necesidad de crear variables globales en tu programa. Empiezas a adquirir malas prácticas

Lo que sí está mal es el uso de las variables:

```
double fzi = Ecuacion(std:: complex<double> zi);
```

El compilador ya sabe que `zi` es de tipo `std::complex<double>`, no hace falta que se lo recuerdes a cada uso. El compilador espera que la llamada la hagas así:

```
double fzi = Ecuacion(zi);
```

Y lo mismo para el resto de llamadas.

Es decir, el compilador ya sabe de qué tipo es cada variable, lo que no sabe es qué quieres hacer con ellas... tu implementas tu algoritmo y el compilador se encarará de comprobar si las llamadas son válidas o no.

Otro problema que veo es que usas variables antes de estar las mismas inicializadas:

```
double r;
double im;
int main() {
    std:: complex<double> zi(r,im);
```

¿Qué valor tienen `r` e `im` cuando se crea la variable `zi`? Dado que `r` e `im` no están inicializadas aún, su valor es indeterminado y, en consecuencia, el valor de `zi` será igualmente indeterminado.

Que posteriormente inicialices `r` e `im` no tendrá impacto alguno en `zi`, luego su valor quedará definido en la primera línea del `main`.

Debes inicializar antes de usar:

```
std:: cout << "Parte real" << std:: endl;
std:: cin >> r;
std:: cout << "Parte imaginaria" << std:: endl;
std:: cin >> im;
std:: complex<double> zi(r,im);
```

Aquí entra en juego también el abuso de las variables globales. Si declaras las variables limitando su vida al máximo el error habría aparecido solo:

```
int main() {
    std:: complex<double> zi(r,im); // error, r e im no están declaradas
    std:: cout << "Parte real" << std:: endl;
    double r;
    std:: cin >> r;
    std:: cout << "Parte imaginaria" << std:: endl;
    double im;
    std:: cin >> im;
```

Así que, como ves, limitar la vida de las variables ayuda a encontrar errores que, de otra forma, podrían ser complicados de localizar

Comment: Como apunte... Él retorna de las funciones datos de tipo `float`, pero luego asigna variables de tipo `double` al resultado de dichas funciones. ¿No sería más lógico directamente definir las funciones como `double Ecuacion (double zi)`? Es simple curiosidad, que lo mismo me estoy equivocando yo.

Comment: Con eso puedes perder precisión, pero sí, sería algo más a corregir ... si pongo todas las cosas en la respuesta al final queda kilométrica y nadie la leería

Comment: Lo digo porque cuando comencé a programar no me enteré muy bien de los tipos de variables que había, me quedé con la idea de "enteros" y "decimales". Y años después tuve que coger un proyecto empezado que trabajaba con `double`, yo implementé variables con `float` y el resultado era de todo menos bonito. Hasta que caí en el tipo de dato que tenía cada variable. Por otro lado, he intentado compilar el código con las modificaciones y sigue habiendo errores en las funciones, como intentar operar números complejos con `int`. El compilador avisa de eso, por lo que será fácil de corregir.

Comment: @Londo no te quito la razón, quizás sería conveniente que añadieses una respuesta con esos datos. Alargar mi respuesta no veo que vaya a mejorar el aporte